# Carry over WooCommerce cart's Calculate Shipping state field value into checkout billing state field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a WooCommerce website. For some reason, when a customer is on the cart page and fills out the Calculate Shipping fields of city, state, and zip code, then goes to checkout, the state selected in the Calculate Shipping field doesn't stay selected in the checkout page's billing form. The user has to reselect it. Too many users are getting frustrated with this. How do I get the Calculate Shipping's "State" field value to carry over to the checkout page?

[image]

[image]

For the record, this is using the *default* WooCommerce templates for everything. Nothing has been forked. There are no filters or actions in functions.php in play for cart or checkout. So the code has no modifications to show here in this post. It's just the default WooCommerce code. Somehow it's just not remembering the user's "State" selection from cart to checkout.

Answer (score 0):

I asked WooCommerce support about this and their answer was

> This is intentional functionality. The shipping calculator on the cart page is not meant to be the customer's actual address, necessarily, but just a quick calculation of what the shipping costs would be if the customer did decide to use that address. It is not necessary to fill these fields out before moving onto the checkout page, either.